# where is the configuration file for the routing and gateway under centos?

Tags: networking, routes, centos, gateway

where is the configuration file for these result ?

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.204   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

there entries aren't found in the following files

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

when i update GATEWAY in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, but when i run

```
route -n
```

it gives me the old result:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.204   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

where i should search to find these entries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check "/etc/network/interfaces" file

Refer the following link:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-add-route-command/

~Shiva